# root able to import python module, but user can't

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I need to import simplemysql module. But getting ImportError. Import doesn't give error for root user.

Can you please help me with this issue?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (32-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:45) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> from simplemysql import SimpleMysql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named simplemysql
>>> 
$ su
Password: 
root@mtk-Inspiron-1525:/home/mtk/.anaconda2# python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from simplemysql import SimpleMysql
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are *different Pythons* called in these two cases:

> Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (32-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:45)
>
> Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02)

Check that you have `simplemysql` installed into the 2.7.11 Anaconda one.

Comment: how do i install simplemysql in anaconda one?

Comment: @mtk try calling `pip install simplemysql` in a non-sudo mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem and i found out that i can only work with the Module if i import MySQLdb first. Installation of simplemysql (as far as i remember) only worked with a cmd ran as admin on Windows 8.